# How to build meteor mobile app meteor server is deployed in remote server

Tags: android, meteor, amazon-ec2, meteor-helper

I developed an Android app. While development server and client runs in same machine. I hosted meteor bundle in remote server which is hosted in EC2. Now  my mobile apps `Meteor.call` should use EC2 `Meteor.methods`. Is there a way? How to build apk to use  remote server.

Answer (score 3):

You build it for another server (~/Desktop is set to where you want the output to come to):

```
meteor build ~/Desktop --server http://<ec2_ip>:<port>
```

For Android you also need to sign the app and zipalign it or it will give you errors.

You will also need to upload the bundle from the output directory to your EC2 server so the manifest matches your app's apk. If you don't do this the app will update itself first when you load it the first time.

There is a complete set of instructions given by MDG here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-submit-your-Android-app-to-Play-Store

Comment: Thanks Akshat. I found the problem. Actually my problem in Server blocks `cross orgin` this is the error am getting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ec2-11-11-11-111.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/sockjs/info?cb=3g6hsj4d5q. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://meteor.local' is therefore not allowed access.`. Do you have solution?

Comment: @BlueBells This issue will popup for HTTP requests unless you proxy them natively. To get passed the initial websocket connection be sure you set ROOT_URL correctly and use a proper domain or IP address over the variable EC2 uri.